# Foreach loop only reading the last item

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I need the code to check checkboxes if their code is on the list and to uncheck if not on the list. The foreach loop is only reading the last item in the list.
So, if the last item is WNM, only the WNM checkbox will be checked even though other matching items are on the list. The list only has one row of strings in it.

The code:

```
    foreach (string k in list)
    {
        if (k == "BGN")
        {
            CBBGN.Checked = true;
        }
        else { CBBGN.Checked = false; }
        if (k == "LAN")
        {
            CBLan.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CBLan.Checked = false;
        }
        if (k == "FGN")
        {
            CBFGN.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CBFGN.Checked = false;
        }
        if (k == "WNM")
        {
            CBWNM.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CBWNM.Checked = false;
        }
        if (k == "GGN")
        {
            CBGGN.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CBGGN.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check list with a breakpoint to see the length.

Comment: How is `list` generated?

Comment: `The list only has one row of strings in it.` <= what do you mean by this? What is the exact content of `list`?

Comment: "the list has one row of strings in it", so the loop should only execute once (one time for each ITEM in the list).  It seems that each "tag" is 3 characters long.  - are you sure you want a list, and not to parse the string?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? If your last item in the list is "WNM" it will uncheck all other checkboxes.

Comment: Breakpoints are your best friend....

Comment: use switch instead of if else in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You iterate over the loop and with each iteration you undo the iteration that proceeded it as it will hit the `false` of each `if` statement for that item.

A better structure would be set all `Checked` states to `false` initially. Then iterate over the list and only set the `Checked` state to `true` IF it occurs in the list but do not set it to `false`.

You can also do this which is simpler to read, you can use a HashSet to increase performance if the list can be large. (*thanks @AlexeiLevenkov*)

```
CBBGN.Checked = list.Contains("BGN");
CBLan.Checked = list.Contains("LAN");
CBFGN.Checked = list.Contains("FGN");
CBWNM.Checked = list.Contains("WNM");
CBGGN.Checked = list.Contains("GGN");
```

Original Fix

```
CBBGN.Checked = false;
CBLan.Checked = false;
CBFGN.Checked = false;
CBWNM.Checked = false;
CBGGN.Checked = false;


foreach (string k in list)
{
    if (k == "BGN")
        CBBGN.Checked = true;
    if (k == "LAN")
        CBLan.Checked = true;
    if (k == "FGN")
        CBFGN.Checked = true;
    if (k == "WNM")
        CBWNM.Checked = true;
    if (k == "GGN")
        CBGGN.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: use switch better suited here

Comment: `CBBGN.Checked = list.Contains("BGN")` could be easier to read and if `list` is `HashSet<string>` it would have the same perf.

Comment: I deleted my comments as I got a better read on the OP situation, and agree with the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control your checkboxes by finding if an element is in the list, just use Linq:

```
CBBGN.Checked = list.Any(s => s == "BGN");
CBLan.Checked = list.Any(s => s == "LAN");
CBFGN.Checked = list.Any(s => s == "FGN");
CBWNM.Checked = list.Any(s => s == "WNM");
CBGGN.Checked = list.Any(s => s == "GGN");
```

Using a HashSet instead as proposed by Alexei and shown by Igor would of course be better performance wise and readability.